# Common Vehicle Type Recognition Algorithms

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, image-processing, machine-learning

I am trying to write a program in C++ using the OpenCV toolkit that accepts a single back-view image containing at most one vehicle as input, and then classifies it into 4 categories:

- Car
- Truck
- Light Truck
- Bus

What I am looking for is the common algorithms that are usually used for challenges like this.

Comment: So you assume that there is exactly one vehicle in the image and only want to classify? Any assumptions about the angle (backview sideview etc)?

Comment: Most common method should be SVM training with appropriate features (maybe HoG). Other classification learning methods are neural nets and decision trees.

Comment: Neural networks. You can also use HaarCascade classifiers with OpenCV